# Detect if script is running in Runkit

Tags: javascript, runkit.com

How do I detect if the current environment which my script runs in is [Runkit](https://runkit.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runkit defines a lot of environmental variables that are sufficient to detect this. More specifically, we can detect `RUNKIT_ENDPOINT_PATH`, `RUNKIT_ENDPOINT_URL`, `RUNKIT_MOUNT_PATH` and `RUNKIT_HOST`:

```js
const isRunkit = typeof process.env.RUNKIT_ENDPOINT_PATH === "string" &&
    typeof process.env.RUNKIT_ENDPOINT_URL === "string" &&
    typeof process.env.RUNKIT_MOUNT_PATH === "string" &&
    process.env.RUNKIT_HOST === "runkit.com"
```